# Titlesec package - paragraph level headings as margin notes

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs, sidenotes

After hours of pointless googling around I did not manage to find out how... I'm new to LaTeX templates and now I'm trying to make simple (?) modification so that I could have paragraph level headings to appear as margin notes. Paragraph level heading should be on the left side of the following paragraph, like in certain CV styles.

Could this be done with article + titlesec?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=2cm,includeheadfoot,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bf,pagestyles,raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

% Setup for page layout (titlesec)
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\thepage][][\thesubsecton\quad\subsectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
}
\widenhead*{2cm}{0cm}
\pagestyle{main}

% Setup for headings (titlesec)
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thesection}}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thesubsection}}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thesubsubsection}}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\theparagraph}}{15pt}{}    
\titlespacing*{\section}{-45pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-45pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-45pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{-45pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Perhaps the technique [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9715/margin-notes-and-subsection-titles-in-both-sides-of-a-two-column-document) could be used, wrapping the paragraph call within a marginpar?

Comment: Roger that. Regarding the original question; In my actual templates (+ 20 templates) I'm using several other packages required for coherent formatting etc. that may or may not work with other classes so I feel that I'm kinda bound to article class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the `leftmargin` option.

So, for your `paragraph` definition, something like,

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\filleft}{\theparagraph}{15pt}{}
```

and

```
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{65pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=2cm,includeheadfoot,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bf,pagestyles,raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

% Setup for page layout (titlesec)
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \headrule
  \sethead[\thepage][][\thesubsecton\quad\subsectiontitle]{\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage}
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
}
\widenhead*{2cm}{0cm}
\pagestyle{main}

% Setup for headings (titlesec)
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thesection}}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thesubsection}}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\makebox[30pt][r]{\thesubsubsection}}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\filleft}{\theparagraph}{15pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-45pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-45pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-45pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{65pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}


\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Substituting `filleft` with `filright` you get

[image]

Comment: @Pasi You're welcome. Happy it helped you.